# MySQL -strange behavior between running queries in a stored proc and outside

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, insert

In MySQL I created a table, and set the third column of that tables 'default value' to '0'.

However in a stored proc when I have the statement:

```
INSERT INTO table (column1, column2, column4) VALUES('...','...','...');
```

I get a result where the third column is null even though I set the default value to 0.

[image]

However when I run the query by itself outside the stored proc

```
INSERT INTO table (column1, column2, column4) VALUES('...','...','...');
```

I gett the proper output

[image]

**Why when running the same insert command in a stored proc does the value reset to null?**

Comment: I can't reproduce it: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5ec1bd/1

Comment: Hmm I am running Mysql Workbench, column 3 is INT(11) default '0'. I don't know what else to add

Comment: What version of MySQL?

Comment: @Barmar 6.1 version